# AWS S3 Postgres Extension `ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x8b`

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, amazon-s3

1. save Spark DataFrame to S3 as CSV with GZip compression

   ```py
   (
       df.write
       .option("header", True)
       .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
       .mode(mode)
       .csv(s3_uri, compression=compression))
   ```
2. set tag `Content-Encoding` to `gzip`
   [image]
3. execute postgres extension to `COPY` from S3 to a table

   ```sql
   SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
     'public.mytable1', '', '(format csv, header true)',
     aws_commons.create_s3_uri('my-bucket-1', 'my/object/key/part-00000-...-1-c000.csv', 'us-east-1')
   );
   ```

Answer (score 4):

AWS documentation gives incorrect instructions to set object metadata. if you manually set metadata, it will simply treat your tag as an arbitrary string instead of recognizing Content-Encoding as a reserved keyword.

The default metadata behavior will cause error:
[image]

Force system-defined tags (rather than the default User-defined tags):
[image]

Wasted hours and 4 peoples' time on this. Feedback to AWS docs team has been submitted.